# SSIS script task results

Tags: ssis

In the SSIS package, two paths lead into a flat file and the third path has a script task that produces an excel spreadsheet of the data that results from the script task.  There is a column named 'Type' that is in both the cvs file and the excel spreadsheet, for rows that are a result of the script task, I need for the 'Type' column data to say 'Vendor' and somehow merge those rows into the path that creates the cvs file.  The rows in the script task are produced by several conditions so I don't want to get rid of the script task. Is this possible?

Comment: Would it be possible to post a screenshot of how the DFT looks like to get an idea? Question isn't fully clear. In total are there 2 Script Task (one source one destination (producing Excel?), 2 Flat File Destinations? You now want one more column coming from 'Source' Script Task to get across the three destinations. Is that right?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without more details, like the data flow (are the paths coming from same source and being conditionally split?) , how do you map Vendor to the other rows? , etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible.

In the script task, add the `Type` column with "Vendor" hard-coded as the value.

In the other paths, add the `Type` column with whatever value you want, using a Derived Column transformation.

Then you can use a UNION ALL transformation to combine the Script task rows with the rows in the other path.